# CSS media queries hierarchy in a stylesheet

Tags: css, media-queries

In a mobile first responsive design what would be the hierarchy of media queries.
I'll start write from larger devices to smaller devices or vice versa.

```
max-width: 1024{}
max-width: 768{}
max-width: 320{}

or 
max-width: 320{}
max-width: 768{}
max-width: 1024{}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're working mobile first, it would make more sense to use `min-width`, and go from smallest to largest.

i.e

`general rules with no media query (smallest)`

`min-width: 320{}`

`min-width: 768{}`

`min-width: 1024{}`

Comment: Yup. In OP examples, pages are unstyled over 1024px which is kind of unwelcomed

Comment: Unless OP also has base styles outside of any media queries, which would make this a desktop first approach

Answer (score 0):

It will be like this

```
max-width: 1024{}
max-width: 768{}
max-width: 320{}
```